# SQL/PHP How can I filter this with the use of a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

This database is a very basic concept for a *video rental store*. The database is displayed with the use of PHP (and HTML, CSS, bootstrap, etc).

I have **three** tables:

**tl_dvd**: which holds the basic info about the dvd, duration date, name, language, etc.

[image: tl_dvd]

**tl_order**: which holds the name of the person who rented a movie and the startdate.

[image: tl_order]

**tl_client**: which isn't really relevant to my question/problem, but just holds the first and last name of the clients.

When I'm on the order page it displays all the orders which are currently running. I have one column called `returned` in `tl_order` with a tinyint where `0` **stands for not returned** and `1` **stands for returned**.

There's a button which says '*terug gebracht*' (='received back' in English) which will set the selected order to 1. **The tl_order only displays the orders which are not returned yet (`returned` set on 0).** On the end of the SQL query I've set something like `... AND returned = 0';`

**Here is the part where I'm supposed to use the `LEFT (OUTER?) JOIN`.** If an order is not back (so that means `returned` is still on `0` in `tl_order`) the dvd should not show up in my `tl_dvd` (think of it like we only have one dvd copy for every movie). I've tried these `LEFT JOIN`s in `tl_dvd`:

```
'SELECT * FROM tl_dvd LEFT JOIN tl_order WHERE tl_order.returned = 1';
```

Breaks my page with 500 error.

```
'SELECT * FROM tl_dvd LEFT JOIN tl_order ON tl_order.returned = 1';
```

Doesn't give me an error but spams every title like 3 times.

Can someone explain me how to tackle this issue or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When joining tables, you'll get one line per combination of the 2 tables, even if you don't display the fields of the 2 tables. Try selecting from both tables to understand what I mean. You miss the ON clause to associate the ids in your JOIN.

Comment: It is not clear what you want output. Please read and act on [mcve]. Also please use text whenever possible. Here, instead of images; format tables in code blocks. PS You say "the dvd should not show up in my tl_dvd" but don't you mean, in the *output*? (See my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your queries is that you're not specifying how the tables should be joined (which columns to join on), and so it's returning *everything* from both tables.

Try this:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    tl_dvd left join tl_order on (tl_dvd.titel=tl_order.titel) 
where 
    tl_order.returned = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't clearly explain or give an example of what you want in your query result. But from your examples you might want

```
SELECT *  FROM tl_dvd
LEFT JOIN tl_order
ON tl_dvd.titel = tl_order.titel
WHERE tl_order.returned = 1
```

OUTER JOIN without ON is not standard SQL but MySQL treats absent ON in INNER and OUTER JOIN like `ON 1=1`, which in either case is equivalent to CROSS JOIN.

But it doesn't seem like you really want LEFT JOIN rather than (INNER) JOIN. LEFT JOIN returns (INNER) JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So here besides a row for every dvd order you get row for every nordered dvd, with order info null. Since "If an order is not back [...] the dvd should not show up" seems to say you don't want those extra rows. You'd want the above without 'LEFT' or equivalently (but less clearly)

```
SELECT *  FROM tl_dvd
CROSS JOIN tl_order
WHERE tl_dvd.titel = tl_order.titel
AND tl_order.returned = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rewrite the query to user inner join like the following

```
SELECT * FROM tl_dvd INNER JOIN tl_order ON
tl_dvd.id=tl_order.id //replace the id with the id you would like to join
WHERE tl_order.returned = 1
```